# tmux pane continuation

Tags: linux, vim, tmux

I would like to have a very tall virtual display to browse code in vim.
Is it possible to split tmux into two column panes, so that the right pane continues the left pane?
So that I can scroll in one and it scrolls both appropriately. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open up one pane in tmux, and have the same file opened in two [vertically split windows](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:vsplit) in vim, and use [scrollbind](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'scrollbind') to lock their scrolling to achieve what you're looking for.